# Is there a way to measure cache coherence misses

Tags: performance, cpu-cache

Given a program running on multiple cores, if two or more cores are operating on the same cache line, is there a way to measure the number of cache coherence invalidations/misses there are (i.e. when Core1 writes to the cache line, which then forces Core2 to refresh its copy of the cache line so that both cores are consistent)?

Let me know if I'm using the wrong terminology for this concept.

Comment: The question is too broad in its current form. Specify the architecture, vendors, and microarchitectures that you're interested in. Add the corresponding tags to the question. Are asking about counting in invalidations or misses? It may be useful also to mention what you're going to use these for. Regarding, Core2 refreshing its copy, most real processors don't work like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, **hardware performance counters** can be used to do so.
However, the way to fetch them is use to be dependent of the operating system and your processor. On Linux, the **`perf`** too can be used to track performance counters (more especially `perf stat -e COUNTER_NAME_1,COUNTER_NAME_2,etc.`). Alternatively, on both Linux & Windows, Intel VTune can do this too.

The list of the hardware counters can be retrieved using `perf list` (or with PMU-Tools).

The kind of metric you want to measure looks like **Request For Ownership** (RFO) in the [MESI cache-coherence protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol). Hopefully, most modern (x86_64) processors include hardware events to measure RFOs. On Intel Skylake processors, there are hardware events called `l2_rqsts.all_rfo`, and more precisely `l2_rqsts.code_rd_hit` and `l2_rqsts.code_rd_miss` to do this at the *L2-cache level*. Alternatively, there are many more-advanced RFO-related hardware events that can be used at the *offcore level*.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had searched through `perf list` but was searching for terms like "coherence" and "coherency"; knowing that the term to use is "Request For Ownership" will also be very helpful.

Comment: `l2_rqsts.all_rfo` doesn't really count or even approximate coherence invalidations because it includes both RFO hits and misses and not all misses cause invalidations. The offcore response events is on appropriate way, though, depending on the microarchitecture.

Comment: @HadiBrais could you post a list of possible *offcore response events*  that can be used for measuring cache coherence misses on Intel skylake xp processors? Is there a good source with detailed explanation about events? One line definition in Intel manuals is not descriptive enough.

Comment: @ajit These events are documented in Section 18.3.8.2.1 of the Intel SDM Volume 3. If there is something not clear in that section, you can post a new question here or in the Intel performance monitoring forum.

Comment: Are there any similar events ( or other events can determined the number of cache coherence ) in arm-based CPU?

Comment: I don't know much about ARM PMU events, but It seems most interesting counters are architecture-dependent (like on x86). For example on ARM Neoverse N1, there is a [PMU guide document](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/PJDOC-466751330-547673/r4p1/?lang=en). Reading quickly, I found `L2D_CACHE_INVAL` which might be a good start. I advise you to check the other events (and possibly the document for the other architectures).